# Get Substring Inside String Delimiter SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, substring

How can I extract the substring inside the [..] to the right 
of the designating string Full Name?

Example.

```
'asdfasfasfs Full Name [Lorem,Ipsum] asdfds Client Name [adfore, fipsum] asdfas'
```

Then I want the string

> Lorem, Ipsum

outputted.

I've tried

```
SELECT DECLARE @Parameter VARCHAR(100)
SET @Parameter= 'asdfasfasfs Full Name [Lorem,Ipsum] asdfds Client Name [adfore, fipsum] asdfas'

SELECT  SUBSTRING(@Parameter, CHARINDEX(' Full Name [', X))
```

But I don't know how to get to the location of the [ after Full Name
AND since the string in [...] is of variable length I don't know how to get to the location
of the the closing ].

Comment: What about _[adfore, fipsum]_?

Comment: @Sami No. I only want what's after Full Name.

Comment: Whoever that down voted my question care to explain why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the CharIndex of the first found [ as the start point:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(@s, 
                 CHARINDEX('[', @s, CHARINDEX('Full Name', @s, 1)) + 1, 
                 CHARINDEX(']', @s, CHARINDEX('[', @s, CHARINDEX('Full Name', @s, 1))) 
                 - CHARINDEX('[', @s, CHARINDEX('Full Name', @s, 1)) - 1)
```

`CHARINDEX(']', @s, CHARINDEX('[', @s, CHARINDEX('Full Name', @s, 1)))` - is this charindex of the first `]` after the first `[` following `Full Name`.

From that we subtract the position of the first found `[` from it so as to ascertain the length of the substring.

The `+ 1` in the starting position is to avoid the `[` and the `- 1` in the length is to avoid the `]`.

Edit - Further explanation:

```
DECLARE @s NVARCHAR(255) = N'asdfasfasfs Full Name [Lorem,Ipsum] asdfds Client Name [adfore, fipsum] asdfas'
```

The first piece of information I needed was the location of the "label" that represented the data of interest. You wished for the data following "Full Name" so I sought out the location of "Full Name" within the string.

```
DECLARE @label NVARCHAR(100) = N'Full Name'
DECLARE @labelPos INT = CHARINDEX('Full Name', @s, 1)
```

Once I had the location of the label, it was necessary to find the position of the first instances of opening/closing brackets which came after the label.

```
DECLARE @openBracketPos INT = CHARINDEX('[', @s, @labelPos)
DECLARE @closeBracketPos INT = CHARINDEX(']', @s, @openBracketPos)
```

With those positions, I could now ascertain the length of the data within the brackets. It is necessary to subtract an additional character due to the difference including one of the brackets.

```
DECLARE @fieldLength INT = @closeBracketPos - @openBracketPos - 1
```

Once I had all of those pieces of information, it was simply a matter of constructing a SUBSTRING call to extract that portion of the string. The +1 tells the SUBSTRING to start on the character FOLLOWING the opening bracket.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(@s, @openBracketPos + 1, @fieldLength)
```

In order to avoid the extra steps and variable usage, I simply combined all of the above into a single statement. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you! This would have taken me hours to figure out. Shame it takes SQL Server so much to manipulate strings. Mind if you share the thought process behind your solution?

Answer (score 1):

If open to a TVF...

Being a TVF, it is easy to include in a CROSS APPLY

**Example**

```
DECLARE @Parameter VARCHAR(100)
SET @Parameter= 'asdfasfasfs Full Name [Lorem,Ipsum] asdfds Client Name [adfore, fipsum] asdfas'

Select * 
 From  [dbo].[tvf-Str-Extract](@Parameter,'[',']')
```

**Returns**

```
RetSeq  RetPos  RetVal
1       24      Lorem,Ipsum
2       57      adfore, fipsum
```

**The Function if Interested**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[tvf-Str-Extract] (@String varchar(max),@Delimiter1 varchar(100),@Delimiter2 varchar(100))
Returns Table 
As
Return (  

with   cte1(N)   as (Select 1 From (values(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) N(N)),
       cte2(N)   as (Select Top (IsNull(DataLength(@String),0)) Row_Number() over (Order By (Select NULL)) From (Select N=1 From cte1 N1,cte1 N2,cte1 N3,cte1 N4,cte1 N5,cte1 N6) A ),
       cte3(N)   as (Select 1 Union All Select t.N+DataLength(@Delimiter1) From cte2 t Where Substring(@String,t.N,DataLength(@Delimiter1)) = @Delimiter1),
       cte4(N,L) as (Select S.N,IsNull(NullIf(CharIndex(@Delimiter1,@String,s.N),0)-S.N,8000) From cte3 S)

Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By N)
      ,RetPos = N
      ,RetVal = left(RetVal,charindex(@Delimiter2,RetVal)-1) 
 From  ( Select *,RetVal = Substring(@String, N, L) From cte4 ) A
 Where charindex(@Delimiter2,RetVal)>1
)
/*
Max Length of String 1MM characters

Declare @String varchar(max) = 'Dear [[FirstName]] [[LastName]], ...'
Select * From [dbo].[tvf-Str-Extract] (@String,'[[',']]')
*/
```

Comment: Would be an interesting exercise to provide a fourth parameter for the keyword(s) to look for when returning the selected values within the `[]`. e.g. `[dbo].[tvf-Str-Extract](@String, '[', '[', 'Full Name')` which would return the `[...]` value following `Full Name`.

Comment: @Forty3 You could have a more targeted extract   [dbo].[tvf-Str-Extract](@Parameter,'Full Name [',']')

Comment: Ah - clever. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> Then I want the string `Lorem, Ipsum`outputted.

Use `CHARINDEX()` as

```
DECLARE @Parameter VARCHAR(100)
SET @Parameter= 'asdfasfasfs Full Name [Lorem,Ipsum] asdfds Client Name [adfore, fipsum] asdfas'

SELECT SUBSTRING(@Parameter,
                 CHARINDEX('[', @Parameter)+1, 
                 CHARINDEX(']', @Parameter)-CHARINDEX('[', @Parameter)-1)
```

Comment: This works for the first instance of `[...]` value but not if OP wanted the `[...]` value following `Client Name`.

Comment: @Forty3 I know, I leave a comment under his Q and he doesn't respond, So I answered as he said. Nothing more.

Comment: Good point - I inferred the requirement of being able to designate alternative precursor values for searching within the string. Admittedly, that requirement wasn't explicitly stated.